# Import Multiple Stored Procedures Nightly into All Databases

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, import

I have what appears to be a strange use case that I have been unable to find an answer too on Google. I have a website with a SQL server backend which grabs a copy of several different databases nightly from our different clients in order to keep the latest information on the web. The website utilizes 14 different stored procedures to get all of the information it needs as a user navigates the site.

Up until now, I have been manually updating these procedures in each customers database to ensure they always have the latest. This is difficult, however, as I do not have great remote connections into each of them and some require coordination with their IT department. My goal instead would be to setup some nightly task or script that would look in a folder and run every .sql file in the folder against every database.

This is where I have been unable to make headway, I know how to use SQLCMD to run a procedure through the task scheduler, but I don't know how to do that while utilizing a dynamic list of databases. I already have a script setup to do the restore operation on each database from a .bat file that is FTPed onto the server, is it possible to use xp_cmdshell to run each file in a folder against a database stored in a variable? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Is SSIS an option? You could do this by passing the servername and/or connection string as a parameter.

Comment: Sadly no, because we offer our website to our customers free of charge, I am only able to use the express edition. This means that I need to be able to do everything with either SQLCMD and a bat file or with xp_cmdshell, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Powershell and program as you want. You can do everything you want from powershell script. Just Google what you need with Powershell, you will get the answer. Also, You can use sqlcmd in powershell to run sql queries against any database. Not only that, you can read each file from your folder and run one by one.

Finally, you want to schedule your powershell script to run nightly, one way would be Task Scheduler or node or any custom program or service.

Just google with right keyword, you will get tons of resources.

Hope you have some ideas now to move forward.